# Difference between Object.getPrototypeOf vs __proto__

Tags: javascript

I know that the latter is non-standard. But Is there a difference between `Object.getPrototypeOf` vs `__proto__`? I'm investigating how the prototype chain in javascript works, and would like to be clear on this part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf):

> Object.getPrototypeOf() is the standard implementation of the old and deprecated object.__proto__ property. However it is a read-only method.

So basically they accomplish the same thing if you are reading the value, except `__proto__` is non-standard. `__proto__` also potentially lets you set the prototype of an existing object, but generally that's not a good idea, so the standard now would be to use a constructor function or `Object.create` to create an object with a specific prototype. That said, the ES6 spec also defines a `setPrototypeOf` for setting the prototype of an object as well, though for performance reasons, it's best to avoid that unless explicitly necessary.

Answer (score 8):

Initially, `__proto__` was a Mozilla-only hack in early versions of Mozilla browsers (Firefox prior to 3.5). It was codified in the ECMAScript 3.1 only in 2008.

One difference is that `__proto__` can be changed (a bad design practice though) while `getPrototypeOf` is a reading function.

```
var parentObject = {"parentKey" : "parentValue"};
var childObject = {"childKey" : "childValue"};
childObject.__proto__ = parentObject;
console.log(childObject.parentKey); // parentValue
Object.getPrototypeOf(childObject) = {"parentKey" : "newValue"};
// ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Another difference is how they handle the unlikely case of a name conflict:

```
var myObject = { __proto__ : "conflicts", getPrototypeOf : function () {return "does not conflict"} };
console.log( myObject.getPrototypeOf() ); // "does not conflict"
// all objects inherit from Object.prototype, not Object, so there is no conflict
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(myObject) ) // Object {}
console.log( myObject.__proto__ ); // Object {}, the value "conflicts" is lost
```

Comment: Last para is wrong because **you are confused.** An object's prototype has `isPrototypeOf` prop. **Not** `getPrototypeOf`. `Object` is a function and is **not** the prototype of an object. ¶ The first line of your code should write `isPrototypeOf` instead of `getPrototypeOf`, in other words your answer in the last para is not answering this question but another.

Answer (score 5):

[Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) treats ≪__proto__≫ as a [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get):

```
_ = new Proxy({}, {
  get:z=>console.log('a'),
  getPrototypeOf:z=>console.log('b'),
});
_.__proto__/*a*/
```

—and ≪getPrototypeOf≫ as a [getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/getPrototypeOf):

```
_ = new Proxy({}, {
  get:z=>console.log('a'),
  getPrototypeOf:z=>console.log('b'),
});
Object.getPrototypeOf(_)/*b*/
```

Answer (score 0):

### Summary:

In javascript  The `__proto__` property of an object and the `Object.getPrototypeOf()` method are both ways to access the prototype of an object. They both give us access to a **reference** of the prototype property.

> What is the difference then?

Because `__proto__` is simply a property of an object and was put there back in the day to access the prototype of an object. `__proto__` is now deprecated and there is a chance that certain JS engines don't support this property anymore. `Object.getPrototypeOf()` and `Object.setPrototypeOf()` are the function which now should be used in order to retrieve a prototype.

### Example:

```js
function Dog (name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Dog.prototype.bark = function () { console.log('woof'); };

let dog = new Dog('fluffie');

// DON'T:
// Old method using __proto__ deprecated!
console.log(dog.__proto__);

// DO:
// Using the newer getPrototypeOf function
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(dog));

// What about climbing up the prototype chain like this?
console.log(dog.__proto__.__proto__);

// We can simply nest the Object.getPrototypeOf() method calls like this:
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(dog)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers here but I didn't see anyone mention the difference in how they behave when getting the prototype of an object.

The biggest difference is that if object `obj` does not have `Object.prototype` in its prototype chain, or if `__proto__` exists as a property elsewhere in its prototype chain, then you can't get its prototype with `var prototype = obj.__proto__` because that won't reference `Object.prototype.__proto__`. The work around is to use `Object.prototype.__lookupGetter__('__proto__').call(obj)`.

Another difference is that [Object.getPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf#non-object_coercion) throws in old browsers if you pass it a primitive value. However that behavior was changed in ES6 to only throw if passed `null` or `undefined`, same as `Object.prototype.__proto__` in modern browsers. Now in the case of a primitive, they both return its wrapper object's prototype.

Also worth noting is that `Object.prototype.__proto__` was implemented differently in different browsers before it was eventually standardized. That and it is deprecated which means it could be removed at any time.

**In Conclusion:**

In modern browsers, there is no difference in how they get the prototype of an object as long as you have a proper reference to `Object.prototype.__proto__` when accessing an object's `__proto__` property. That and `Object.prototype.__proto__` is deprecated and could be removed at any time, so don't use it.